# Trouble with mod_rewrite, subdomain and codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a codeigniter installation at example.com/ci.
I have a subdomain foo.example.com.  The document root for the foo subdomain is set to be home/public_html/ci.

I'm using the following rule in .htaccess to send requests for foo.example.com to example.com/ci/city/foo.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/ci/city/%1/$1 [L]
```

It all works like I want it to except that the address bar url changes from foo.example.com to example.com/ci/city/foo. I would like it to remain foo.example.com. There is no R=301 in the RewriteRule (used to be but I removed it).  The .htaccess file is in the ci/ folder and the rule is above all the codeigniter stuff.

The redirect works perfectly and the url remains foo.example.com with (Jon Lin's answer)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/city/
 RewriteRule (.*) /city/%1/$1 [L]
```

but the codeigniter default controller is called instead of the foo method in the city controller.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work correctly using the following rewrite rule

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/city/
 RewriteRule (.*) /city/%1/$1 [L]
```

and by setting

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

in the codeigniter config file.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

When your rewrite rule's target has an `http://example.com` in it, a 302 redirect is implicit regardless of whether an `R` flag is used or not. You need to provide the URI path based on the subdomain's document root, so I'm assuming you want something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/city/
RewriteRule (.*) /city/%1/$1 [L]
```

If the subdomain's document root is in the `/ci/` directory.

The other option is to use the `P` flag to reverse proxy the request:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/ci/city/%1/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When trying the first solution I get a 500 Server error.  my subdomain's document root is the /ci directory.  The second solution results in 

Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
X-Forwarded-Host
/n

Comment: @smrkem made an edit to prevent the loop in the first one from looping.

Comment: Your fix got rid of the server error, thanks - but it's just going to the default controller inside codeigniter. This is what happens when there is no rewrite rule at all.  My intention is to call the city controller and the foo function within it

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary with this (might need to finesse it to fit your server and conditions), but doing some testing on my Mac, here's what I had mild success with:

#### Directory Structure

```
public_html/
  ci/
    application/
    system/
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

I'm assuming that you have other stuff in your root `public_html` directory. So I'm letting the .htaccess focus on the CodeIgniter-related stuff by leaving it in the `ci` dir.

#### .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.ciwildsub\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/city/%1/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's fairly self explanatory, but the first block is your subdomain check. I didn't bother excluding `www` but you may want to (as I said, your mileage may vary). The second block is a standard CodeIgniter `index.php` removal.

These rules will only apply to `sub.example.com` or `example.com/ci/` URLs, since as I said, I assume your root has stuff that shouldn't be disturbed by rewrites.

#### CodeIgniter Config

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

Because of the way Apache handles a URL like `example.com/index.php/controller/method`, it bypasses the `index.php` and handles it like any other directory segment. Also, mod_rewrite doesn't necessarily *stop* at the `[L]` tag -- it stops processing the .htaccess at that point, passes through the RewriteRule, and then runs that URL through the .htaccess. Setting `PATH_INFO` helps make sure CodeIgniter pulls the current URI correctly, and our .htaccess doesn't get stuck in a validation loop.

I will note, though, that I'm not entirely happy with what I see in my RewriteLog output -- there *has* to be a way to optimize this further, I'm just not sure of it yet (I'm done tinkering with this for today!). Sorry if any of the explanation here is a little out of whack - I'm not a server admin or mod_rewrite expert, I've just had fun tinkering with this. If I manage to find a better solution, I'll be sure to update this.

---

Looks like the [`END` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) would be perfect for situations like this (to prevent `[L]` loops), but it's only available in Apache 2.3.9+. The search continues.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Your rules give me a 500 error on the seerver which I can't diagnose since I don't have access to the RewriteLog.  Your codeigniter config however was the second half of my solution.  I had to change it from 'PATH_INFO' to 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' but it's now accessing the proper controller.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, setups can vary so much, it's hard to give you a for-sure answer without having an exact duplicate. Glad you were able to get everything working, though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /file_path/to/subdomain
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```